# How to replace a join workflow in firestore?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have an app where I record orders and bills in firestore. Each order and bill references a customer and each customer is in a group. Since I need to allow filtering by customer group, I store the groupId in orders/bills as well. The difficult part is when someone wants to change the group of the customer. Is the only solution for me to change groupId on all orders and bills for that customer?

What if that number of updates crosses 500 - the risk for me then is that I can't do it in a batch and so I am unable to guarantee correctness.
What is the recommended pattern to solve such a use case which in sql would simply require joining the orders/bills table with customers table?

Comment: Did the answer by @BittorH help you?

Answer (score 0):

If you are still not using it, I would suggest to implement an architecture to your document similar to this one that can help you moving customers from one group to another.

[image]

If you do something like this, you don't need to specify a groupId for every order and bill because they will be inside of the customer and when you move this one, all the data associated will be moving with him.

Now, I'm assuming that you are using this architecture and that you want to change the group of the customer.

To move all the customer data from one group to another, you can follow these steps:

1. Get all the data from the desired customer.
2. Copy this data into the new group.
3. Delete this data from the previous group.

You will get this

[image]